# Checking if two struct instances are different in Swift elegantly

Tags: swift, functional-programming, frameworks, swift-extensions

I made a state engine for Swift but there is something that I would like to improve in a significant way.

It is an open-source project, you can check it out here: https://github.com/mrtksn/SwiftyState

The thing that I would like to improve is the way state changes are handled.

Right now, state changes are handled like this:

```
let subscription = SwiftyState().subscribe { [weak self] in
    let state = $0 as! MyStore
    let oldState = $1 as? MyStore

    /// Your code goes here
}
```

You subscribe to the state changes and whenever an action is called and done changing the state, the subscribers are called and the old state and the new state are passed along. The state is a struct.

Since this will be run every single time the state changes, the user needs to check if the state change is relevant to that part of the code. If will look like something like this:

```
let subscription = SwiftyState().subscribe { [weak self] in
    let state = $0 as! MyStore
    let oldState = $1 as? MyStore

if state.userName != oldState.userName {
     self?.nameLabel.text = state.userName
    }
}
```

What I would like to have is a way to do that with less code, maybe something like this:

```
let subscription = SwiftyState().subscribe { [weak self] in
    let state = $0 as! MyStore
    let oldState = $1 as? MyStore

    /// Maybe assinging a closure to run when the state is changed
    state.userName.hasChanged = {
          self?.nameLabel.text = state.userName
    }

   /// Or maybe just tagging a property as changed 
   if state.userName.hasChanged {
      self?.nameLabel.text = state.userName
   }
   /// Or maybe having a list of changes in the state object
   if state.changes.contain("nameLabel") {
     self?.nameLabel.text = state.userName
   }
}
```

I considered creating an extension but I had limited success so far. I have some ideas but I am running in some problems that lead to unsatisfactory results.

Maybe the creativity of the StackOverflow or the expertise in Swift can help me reduce the boilerplate here?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To compare custom types in Swift, conform that type to **`Equatable protocol`** and implement its `public static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool` method.

Here is an example of how you can do that. Since you haven't added the definition of `MyStore`, you can implement the same thing there as well.

```
struct MyStore: Equatable {
    var userName: String

    static func == (lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.userName == rhs.userName
    }
}
```

In the above method, add all those properties based on which you want to compare the instances of `MyStruct`. Currently, I've only used `userName` for the comparison.

Comparing 2 `structs` like,

```
let s1 = MyStruct(userName: "John")
let s2 = MyStruct(userName: "Annie")
if s1 == s2 {
    print("Equal")
} else {
    print("Unequal")
}
```

Same is valid of your custom type is a `class`.

Comment: Sure, we can compare structs whole structs but  I want to do struct property comparison and do it in an elegant way, reducing code while preserving IDE functions like autocomplete. Check my examples.

Comment: Why don't you simply do `oldState.userName == newState.userName`?

Comment: That's what I do currently but it doesn' look nice and can get quite crowded since I need to type the property name twice. I want to get away with tying it just once. I'm looking into writing extension for the Equatable protocol but I have to find a way to limit it only to my struct and also there are other complications like storing the old state inside the new state, accessing properties by keyPath etc.